# How secure is the Azure Pipelines Agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How secure are the Azure Pipelines hosted Agents and can they be used for more sensitive tasks like code signing?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [container jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to run your  builds.  This ensures that everything is done within a disposable container and removed once your task is over.  You can inject secrets via Azure KeyVault.